# Bounds for the expectation of the max

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider the following expected value
$$
E(\max\{a_1+\epsilon_1, a_2+\epsilon_2,...,a_n+\epsilon_n\})
$$
where the expectation is taken with respect to the random variables $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n)$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ are real numbers.

Can we say whether $E(\max\{a_1+\epsilon_1, a_2+\epsilon_2,...,a_n+\epsilon_n\})$ is greater or smaller than $\max\{a_1,...,a_n\}$?

Can we characterise some upper or lower bound of  $E(\max\{a_1+\epsilon_1, a_2+\epsilon_2,...,a_n+\epsilon_n\})$ that does not depend on the distribution of $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the easiest case $n=1$. $E[a+\epsilon]=a+E[\epsilon]$ and it can be either greater or smaller than $a$ based on the distribution of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose $E(\epsilon)=0$. The answer to my question is still NO?

Comment: @user3285148 for $a_i=a$, the answer would be YES. But, the other case didn't seem (to me) trivial to prove or give counter example. Would be a good question though.